# Does it make sense to keep answers with no upvotes?

Tags: discussion, answers

Those who read it didn't found it useful*.
It doesn't give me reputation.

*Lets assume it's been a long time since I posted the answer, so most chances, that the answer status won't be changed.

Comment: You never know: I've come across (and upvoted) 0-score answers on years-old questions that solved my problem. Do you feel it actually *is* helpful? (Is it largely redundant with other answers? Have you come to decide it's not as useful as you originally estimated?)

Comment: What about unsung hero?

Comment: @TravisJ: of course with 0-score he means no upvote and not accepted. BTW someone could decide to vote and/or accept after years... both the cases happened to me some days ago (on questions from autumn 2012)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to unilaterally delete zero-score answers.

If an answer is to a question in some of the less viewed tags, it is very likely that it may not get any upvotes.

There are even two badges for answers that are accepted but don't get any upvotes - [Tenacious](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero).

Comment: Amen. I have [158 answers, 74 have zero votes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1933347/jmac?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=6). That doesn't mean these are bad answers (and the older ones slowly get votes as time passes and people find them via Google or when posting a new question). They are quite often the *only* answer to that question. So I have to agree wholly with Joshua here.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it makes sense to keep them.

However, I can see both sides. To consult your observations, and out of curiosity, I went looking at the source of all answers on stackoverflow - Jon Skeet. After looking at some of Jon Skeet's 0 upvoted answers (shocking, I know.. resist the urge to regurgitate rainbows) from a long time ago they actually do not seem to provide information which was all that useful to the OP. Please note that this was only like 4 of 100 of Jon's first answers on the site (I idolize Jon and am not trying to insinuate he posts bad answers).

To conclude: if there are answers which have 0 upvotes and are very old, you may consider reviewing them if you have the time to see if they can be improved from an edit, or perhaps remove them if they truly have not added much to the post. Your time might be best spent helping people with new questions rather than reviewing years-old posts though.

*Postscript* - If you find one of these 0 upvoted answers that is old, it can be helpful to comment on the answer letting the answerer know if there is an opportunity for improvement in the post. I know that I have had comments like these on some of my old answers and I appreciated the opportunity to improve the content. After all, isn't quality content what we are all after here?